# Angular, problems with ngRoute code sequence

Tags: angularjs

I am using ngRoute for reading the url parameters. The problem I have is that I can't get the ID while the code is running. However if try to call it as function I get values from url.

```
.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Survey) {
    $scope.survey = Survey.get({surveyId: $routeParams.id}); //doesn't work

    this.add = function (pageId, pageIndex) {
        console.log($routeParams.id); //works
    };

    $scope.Page = this;
}
```

Do you think there is the way of getting the url parameter while I am making the Survey.get() request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve this would be to wait till the $routeChangeSuccess broadcast had been fired and then to initialise your $scope.survey.

i.e something like this

```
.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){
        $scope.survey = Survey.get({surveyId: $routeParams.id}); //doesn't work
    });
    this.add = function (pageId, pageIndex) {
        console.log($routeParams.id); //works
    };

    $scope.Page = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your controller is called only once on the application startup. That's why your routeconfig isn't set yet and returns undefined. Are you sure you're specifying a controller to your view in your routeconfig?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: I have this in my config
`$routeProvider.when('/backend/surveys/:id/build', {
       controller: 'PagesCtrl'
      });`